# Calculate number of primary and secondary key columns

Tags: sql-server, count, key

Is there a tool or query that will give me output as the total number of primary and secondary keys in a database table?

**UPDATE ANSWER**

Please note that secondary key is different from foreign key.

So **count of no. of primary keys** is possible in 2 ways:-

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON i.object_id = t.object_id AND 

t.type = 'U'
LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties AS EP ON EP.major_id = T.[object_id]
where is_primary_key=1
```

*OR*

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT'
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc IN ('PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT')
```

**To count no. of secondary keys use:**

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON i.object_id = t.object_id AND 

t.type = 'U'
LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties AS EP ON EP.major_id = T.[object_id]
where is_unique=1 and is_primary_key=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 USE database

 SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint,
    SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName, 
    OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName
 FROM sys.objects  
 WHERE type_desc IN ('PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT')

 SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint,
    SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName, 
    OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) AS TableName
 FROM sys.objects  
 WHERE type_desc IN ('FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT')
```

Simple count

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT'
 FROM sys.objects  
 WHERE type_desc IN ('PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT')

 SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT'
 FROM sys.objects  
 WHERE type_desc IN ('FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT')
```

Answer (score 1):

The tool is SQL and this is another method to get what you want. A bit more complex then @kevchadders, but this way you can also make a listing of column names, types, etc

**Count Foreign keys**

```
SELECT count(*) from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND Constraint_Type in ( 'FOREIGN KEY')
    AND Col.Table_Name in (select name from sysobjects where xtype = 'U')
```

**Count Pirmairy keys**

```
    SELECT count(*) from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND Constraint_Type in ('PRIMARY KEY')
    AND Col.Table_Name in (select name from sysobjects where xtype = 'U')
```

**For all tables, show the PK and FK**

```
FK
    SELECT *, Col.Column_Name from 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS Tab, 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE Col 
WHERE 
    Col.Constraint_Name = Tab.Constraint_Name
    AND Col.Table_Name = Tab.Table_Name
    AND Constraint_Type in ('PRIMARY KEY', 'FOREIGN KEY')
    AND Col.Table_Name in (select name from sysobjects where xtype = 'U')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT    'PRIMARY KEYS' AS KeyType, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM      sys.tables AS TB INNER JOIN
          sys.key_constraints AS KC ON KC.parent_object_id = TB.object_id
GROUP BY  KC.type

UNION

SELECT    'FOREIGN KEYS' AS KeyType, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM      sys.tables AS TB INNER JOIN
          sys.foreign_keys AS FK ON FK.referenced_object_id = TB.object_id
GROUP BY  FK.type
```

Comment: OK, primary correct. But I want secondary key count and not foreign key count. Secodnary an foreign keys are different concepts.